# What is the correct Big O Notation for this problem?

Tags: big-o, notation

I had an argument with a friend about the following problem:

If you ran binary search on two data sets of unknown lengths (for instance sorted arrays m and n) and had to define the time complexity for the entire function, what would it be? Would it be O(log(m + n)), or O(log(m)) if m > n and O(log(n)) if n > m?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question and rather belongs to computer science SE or similar.

Comment: From my understanding there are many other questions on the same topic on stack overflow. Should all the other related questions be closed as well?

Comment: Read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228577/on-which-stack-exchange-should-questions-about-asymptotic-runtime-complexity-ana

Answer (score 0):

Its either O(log(m)) if m>n or O(log(n)) if n>m because in general for n elements we have O(log(n)). the worst case means at the worst till what element it may go to that will be the nth or the mth element if either of the two is maximum. note this is for synchronous meaning parallel if asynchronous it will be log(m)+log(n)

Answer (score 0):

You are running two independent searches on two independent arrays, not one search on one large array.
Thus, the complexity of the two operations is just added together - O(log(n)) + O(log(m)). As you mentioned, if n>m, the `m` complexity is negligible and you'd be left with O(log(n)), and vice-versa.

Comment: The reason I ask is because in algebra, the sum of log(n) + log(m) = log(m*n). Does this not apply to big o notation?

Comment: @RoeiBurstein That would be correct **inside** the O only. If you had a large array, that m+n elements long, the Complexity would be O(log(n*m)).

Comment: That makes sense. What you're saying is that you cannot add O(log(n)) + O(log(m)) because they are not inside the same O, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply answer: O(log(m*n)) = O(log(m) + log(n)) = O(log(m)) + O(log(n)) = Math.max(O(log(m)), O(log(n))).